# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React.js after update from 0.11 to 0.13

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I update React.js from 0.11 to 0.13 there appear this error in getOptionToRender.

I read changelog but havent found something usefull. Whats the problem here?

Here is a code:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
var Option = require('./option');
module.exports = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'CategorySelecter',
  shouldComponentUpdate: function () {
    return false;
  },
  getOptionsToRender: function () {
    return this.props.categories.map(function (category) {
      return (
        React.createElement(Option, {key: category.display, input: category})
      );
    });
  },
  handleChange: function (event) {
    this.props.changeCategory(event.target.value);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      React.createElement("div", {className: "container top15"},
        React.createElement("form", null,
          React.createElement("div", {className: "form-group"},
            React.createElement("select", {onChange: this.handleChange, className: "form-control"},
              this.getOptionsToRender()
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Who is setting the categories property? That error only means, that `this.props.categories` is not set.

Comment: @Noch_ein_Kamel but it have worked until i updated

Comment: Please post the code that is responsible for assigning the `categories` prop for this component.